# Python SQLite3 If field == variable

Tags: python, sqlite

I have seen alot of threads to check if the field exists but i am a little confused i was wondering if someone could tell me hwot to check if it exists and to see if it is equal to an input which is a variable.

My code so far

```
import sqlite3
import datetime
import smtplib

now = datetime.datetime.now()
conn = sqlite3.connect("accounts.db")

c = conn.cursor()



def register():
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input ("Password: ")
    date = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M")
    adminlevel = 0

    c.execute("""INSERT INTO accounts
              (username,password,date,adminlevel)
              VALUES(?,?,?,?)""",(username,password,date,adminlevel))
    conn.commit()

    print("You have succesfully registered at " + date, "An email has been sent to you with your information!")
    menu()

from getpass import getpass

def login():
    def loggedin():

        if adminlevel > 0:
            print("Hello There Admin!")
            print("Commands: ")
        else:
            print("Hello there {}".format(username))
            print("Commands: Name, Date, Friend, Logout")





    adminlevel = 0
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    password = getpass("Please enter your password: ")
    admin = c.execute("select 1 from accounts where adminlevel > 0")
    c.execute("select 1 from accounts where username = ? and password = ?", (username, password))
    if c.fetchone():
        print('Hello there! {}'.format(username))
        loggedin()
    else:

        print("Username and Password Not Found!")
        login()

def menu():
    print("="*40)
    print("Login & Registration System")
    print("="*40)

    choice = input("Login or Register? ")

    if choice == "register":
        register()
    elif choice == "login":
        login()


menu()
```

Comment: Do you mean in your `login()` function? You should make more effort to make your question clear - it should not be necessary to read all of the code to figure out what the question _might_ be.

Comment: For starters, `def info():` does nothing (global variables should be declared `global` in the function that uses them) and `username == username:` will always be true - if `username` was defined, that is.

Comment: Don't worry got rid of it now, i have my answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to check the user's credentials in the `login()` function, you can perform a `SELECT` query for that:

```
from getpass import getpass

def login():
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    password = getpass("Please enter your password: ")
    c.execute("select 1 from accounts where username = ? and password = ?", (username, password))
    if c.fetchone():
        print('logged in: {}'.format(username))
    else:
        print("ERROR")
```

This code prompts the user for their username and password (without echoing it to the terminal), and then uses those values to query the database for a matching record in the `account` table. If there is a record, `1` will be returned by `fetchone()` and the user can then be logged in, otherwise the username and/or password are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! if i would like to define loggedin() and grab the username how would i do this? would i need to make username a global varible? then print it etc

Comment: You mean that `loggedin()` is a function that will log the user in? If so then simply pass the user name as an argument to that function, i.e. `loggedin(username)`. You don't need to use global variables.

Comment: Ok, i just made it so when they log in it will call that definition / function then do a set of commands

Comment: Does not recognize it as its not in log in, i tried to put it in the same definition but it referenced before assignment.